# Postgres session is blocked by PID 0 (because of .Net core transactions?)

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, transactions, transactionscope

We use transaction scope in our .Net core application and Postgres DB.
We have found out strange behavior on one of our environments:

[image]

We have the root session with PID 66885 witch blocks all other sessions. And this session is blocked by PID 0 itself.
And if we kill this session, we have the same picture but with other sessions:
[image]

So it is just a cascade (or some kind of tree) of interlocks. And if we go to Locks we see a lot of Exclusive Locks on the one tuple:
[image]

So we have a queue of Exclusive Locks on one company (tuple). The third lock waits for the second one. The second one waits for the first one. But what is the first lock waiting for? What is the strange process with PID = 0?

My assumption is:

- We use .Net transaction scope and the root session is waiting for the commit (confirmation)
- But because of the initial connection was aborted because of the timeout the transaction can't receive the commit.

Does it look like a true and how could we avoid this?

We use - Npgsql (3.2.5), Net.Core (2.2), Postgres (9.6) and have `enlist=true` option in our connection string.

---

**UPD 1: add our transaction settings**

```
  public class DbTransaction : IDbTransaction, IDisposable
  {
    private readonly TransactionScope _innerScope;

    private DbTransaction(TransactionScope scope)
    {
      this._innerScope = scope;
    }

    public static DbTransaction Begin(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
      IsolationLevel isolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
      return new DbTransaction(new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, new TransactionOptions()
      {
        IsolationLevel = isolationLevel,
        Timeout = timeout
      }, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled));
    }

    public void Complete()
    {
      this._innerScope.Complete();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      this._innerScope.Dispose();
    }
  }

  public class DbTransactionScope : IDbTransactionScope
  {
    public IDbTransaction Begin(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
      return (IDbTransaction) DbTransaction.Begin(timeout);
    }

    public IDbTransaction Begin()
    {
      return this.Begin(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3.0));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Distributed transactions happen between databases or other transaction providers, not clients and databases. .NET Core [doesn't even support distributed transactions yet](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14939) - those require MSDTC which obviously only works on Windows. What does the code look like? Does it dispose all `TransactionScope` instances properly? Why is TransactionScope used in the first place, instead of a native transaction?

Comment: As for 2 phase transactions, what does that mean? Two-phase *commit* applies only to distributed transactions which doesn't apply when you only have a *single* database and isn't visible to clients anyway. It looks like the code generates queries that block each other, probably because normal transactions are kept alive longer than they should. That's *very* worrying given PosgreSQL's MVCC model.

Comment: Are you using a single database transaction around an entire web request or business operation in an attempt to emulate `Unit of Work`? That's very bad practice which can seriously harm performance and scalability. UoW or business transactions *don't* have anything to do with database transactions. Database transactions should be short-lived.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have added our transaction settings to the post. Hope it helps to understand what I am talking about.

Comment: And @PanagiotisKanavos - you were completely right. We have no distributed transactions, just simple transactions.

Comment: What's the point of this code? There's already a DbTransaction abstract object that works just fine. `TransactionScope` is used when people want to *avoid* using explicit provider transactions. How is it used? I suspect this class is kept around for too long and  ends up keeping all database transactions open, resulting in blocking

Comment: Are you trying to emulate nested transactions on the client? You can't do that if the database doesn't support it. You can't use two-phase commit to emulate nested transactions either, they are completely different concepts.

Comment: Hi. This post is old, but I've the same trouble with Java app. One record of a big table is locked by PID 0. There are some solution or recipe for this trouble? PG Version 9.6.2

Answer (score 1):

In general you can list the blocked queries in *PostgreSQL* by interrogating table `pg_locks`, in conjunction with method `pg_blocking_pids`. As the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-locks.html) states, the `pg_locks.granted` column is *True if lock is held, false if lock is awaited*. Therefore, it is possible to list blocked PIDs and blocking PIDs with something like this:

```
select
   pid as blocked_pid,
   pg_blocking_pids(pid) as blocked_by,
   concat(pg_namespace.nspname, '.', pg_class.relname) as table,
   pg_locks.*
from pg_catalog.pg_locks
join pg_catalog.pg_class on pg_class.oid = pg_locks.relation
join pg_catalog.pg_namespace on pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace 
where pg_locks.granted = false;
```

Or, based on the `pg_stat_activity` table, using again `pg_blocking_pids` method to detect blocked PIDs:

```
select 
   pid, 
   pg_blocking_pids(pid) as blocked_by, 
   query as blocked_query
from pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity
where pg_blocking_pids(pid)::text != '{}';
```

Then, if you have enough privileges, you can kill the blocking PID with something like:

```
select pg_terminate_backend(PID)
```

When the blocking PID are 0, like in the case of the OP, then they may be prepared transaction. I discovered this [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/15513-94a76c56fa3eed61%40postgresql.org).

The general expectation for a [prepared transaction](https://www.highgo.ca/2020/01/28/understanding-prepared-transactions-and-handling-the-orphans) is to be completed within seconds. However, life happens. You can interrogate the `pg_prepared_xacts` to see if there are some that have lived for too much:

```
select *
from pg_catalog.pg_prepared_xacts;
```

Then you can [kill them](https://www.dbi-services.com/blog/be-careful-with-prepared-transactions-in-postgresql/) (if you have privileges) using their `gid`:

```
rollback prepared 'abc'
```